# SELECT inherit values from Parent (self-references)

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, self-referencing-table

I have 02 tables Rubrique and BulletinRubrique
the table `Rubrique` contain the following columns :

```
ID int not null,
Name, varchar(max) not null,
RubriqueA_ID int null,
RubriqueB_ID int null
```

with data for example :

```
+-------+---------+--------------+--------------+
| ID    | Name    | RubriqueA_ID | RubriqueB_ID | 
+-------+---------+--------------+--------------+
| 1     | R1      |    2         |    3         |
| 2     | R2      |    1         |    2         |
| 3     | R3      |    NULL      |    NULL      |
| 4     | R4      |    NULL      |    6         |
| 5     | R5      |    6         |    NULL      |
| 6     | R6      |    NULL      |    1         |
+-------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

the two columns `RubriqueA_ID`, `RubriqueB_ID` are the foreigns Keys for the same table `Rubrique` (self-referencing) and they might be NULL

For the table `BulletinRubrique` :

```
ID int not null,
EmployeID int not null,
RubriqueID int not null,
Value float not null
```

with data :

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| ID    | EmployeID | Rubrique_ID  | Value      | 
+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+
| B1    | EMP1      | 1            | 150        |
| B1    | EMP1      | 2            | 220        |
| B1    | EMP1      | 3            | 195        |
| B1    | EMP1      | 4            | 170        |
| B1    | EMP1      | 5            | 320        |
| B1    | EMP1      | 6            | 745        |
+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

What I am trying to do is bulding the sql query to get result as :

```
+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+---------+
| ID    | EmployeID | Rubrique_ID  | Value      | A_Value  | B_Value |
+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+---------+
| B1    | EMP1      | 1            | 150        | 220      | 195     |
| B1    | EMP1      | 2            | 220        | 150      | 220     |
| B1    | EMP1      | 3            | 195        | NULL     | NULL    |
| B1    | EMP1      | 4            | 170        | NULL     | 745     |
| B1    | EMP1      | 5            | 320        | 745      | NULL    |
| B1    | EMP1      | 6            | 745        | NULL     | 150     |
+-------+-----------+--------------+------------+----------+---------+
```

Please help me to build this query and thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://rextester.com/FIJE42564 is the working code

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.EmployeID, t2.RubriqueID, t2.Value, t2.A_Value, r2.Value AS B_value  FROM BulletinRubrique r2 
 RIGHT JOIN
   (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.EmployeID, t1.RubriqueID, t1.Value, r1.VALUE AS A_VALUE, t1.B_VALUE  FROM BulletinRubrique r1 
      RIGHT JOIN ( 
        SELECT b.ID, b.EmployeID,b.RubriqueID, b.Value, r.RubriqueA_ID AS A_Value,  r.RubriqueB_ID AS B_Value
        FROM BulletinRubrique b RIGHT JOIN Rubrique r ON r.ID = b.RubriqueID ) t1 
      ON t1.A_Value =  r1.RubriqueID
   )t2 
      ON t2.B_Value =  r2.RubriqueID
      ORDER BY t2.RubriqueID
```

Comment: In BulletinRubrique table EmployeID and RubriqueID can not be int because in your code they are nvarchar(2) and nvarchar(4)

Comment: You are welcome. It is a very advanced question... Have a nice coding...

Answer (score 1):

Being a fan of nested CTE, this is the way I tried solving this

```
WITH CTE1 as(
SELECT 
    BR.Id, BR.EmployeID, BR.RubriqueID, BR.value, R1.Rubriquea_Id, R2.Rubriqueb_Id 
FROM 
    BulletinRubrique BR
LEFT JOIN 
    Rubrique R1 ON R1.Id = BR.RubriqueID
LEFT JOIN 
    Rubrique R2 ON  R2.Id = BR.RubriqueID
),
CTE2 as (
SELECT 
    C1.Id, C1.EmployeID, C1.RubriqueID, C1.value, C2.value as A_Value, C3.value as B_Value 
FROM 
    CTE1 C1
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE1 C2 ON C1.Rubriquea_Id = C2.RubriqueID
LEFT JOIN 
    CTE1 C3 ON  C1.RubriqueB_Id = C3.RubriqueID
)
SELECT C1.Id, 
    C1.EmployeID, 
    C1.RubriqueID, 
    C1.value,
    C1.A_Value as A_Value, 
    C1.B_Value as B_Value  FROM CTE2 C1
ORDER BY Id
```

Comment: I tested your query and it didn't give the desired output, for each row :
Value_A = Value_B = Value, and there is no null value for the columns Value_A and Value_B, Thank you very match for trying helping me

Comment: My bad. Last select statement had values fetching from same column(for A_Value and B_Value). I updated it now.

Comment: It is working, BRAVO my friend, thank you, One more question PLZ, In order to get the result quicker, which method is more performant and optimized : using the CTE or Sub-Query like used in the first answer.

Comment: Well, it depends on the indexes that these tables has. With no index when I looked execution plan for both queries, query from @Dr. Geek looks lot better than mine.

Comment: Thank you my friend, you helped me alot.